# Graph $G$ such that removing an edge leaves $G$ "unchanged"

Tags: graph-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Is there an infinite simple, undirected graph $G = (V,E)$ such that there is $e\in E$ such that $G \cong (V, E\setminus\{e\})$?

(There cannot be a finite graph with that property because removing an edge changes the degree sequence.)

Comment: The graph with no edges is an example.

Comment: An(other) example is the random graph https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7544

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: Why is it so?

Comment: @MarkSapir The graph with no edges isn't such an example, because there is no edge to remove in the first place.

Comment: @MarkSapir If you accept Theorem 1 in the previous reference, this is rather obvious: removing or adding a given edge in a random iid graph is still a random iid graph, and in particular almost surely both graphs are isomorphic to *the* random graph. (here by random iid graph I mean the graph obtained on a given countable infinite set by putting independantly at random an edge between any two pairs of vertices).

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle: I believe you but I do not see why after removing an (any) edge you still get a random graph.

Comment: Is  the random graph connected? I only remember its local properties.

Comment: @MarkSapir Yes, it is connected: better, any two points have a common neighbour.

Comment: OK, it is nice. Perhaps, then, it is the answer the OP is looking for?

Comment: Surely the kind of answer the OP is really looking for is the Rado graph

Comment: @MarkSapir The random graph is characterized up to isomorphism, among countable simple graphs, by the property that, given any two disjoint, finite sets of vertices $A$ and $B$, there exists another vertex adjacent to all the members of $A$ and to none of the members of $B$.  This property is easily seen to be preserved when an edge is removed.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Exactly that property is not clear how to use. A vertex connected to all vertices of $A$ may not be connected to all vertices of $A$ if one of the edges is removed. The thing is that there are at least **two**  such vertices. Also using the fact that the graph is random as mentioned above seems easier.

Comment: To prove the property holds for $A$ and $B$ after the deletion, just apply the property to the original graph with slightly larger $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I am not sure what and to whom you are trying to prove. I know that after removing an edge the graph remains random.

Comment: The random graph property implies that for any such $A$ and $B$, there are *infintely many* vertices each of which is connected to all elements of $A$ and to no elements of $B$. Removing an edge can disturb at most one of them, hence infinitely many remain.

Comment: This property (the one the OP is asking about) is already mentioned on the wiki page of the Rado graph, by the way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph#Robustness_against_finite_changes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An infinite path, the "left half" of its vertices is glued to triangles, the "right half" is glued to paths of length two.

You can remove an edge from one of the triangles without changing the graph.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I report as an answer what I wrote in the comments. The random graph is an example of a connected graph with this property, see [the survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.7544). It even has the property that *for every* $e \in E$, $G$ is isomorphic to $(V,E\setminus \{e\})$ (see Proposition 2 in that survey).

The random graph, introduced by Erdös and Rényi, is the unique graph (up to isomorphism) on a countably infinite vertex set $V$ with the property that for any finitely many distinct vertices $u_1,\dots,u_n,v_1,\dots,v_m$, there is a vertex that is adjacent to all $u_i$'s but to none of the $v_j$'s.

What is intriguing about it is that it appears in many different ways. In particular, and this is the reason for the name, if you draw an edge between any pairs of vertices independently at random with probability $\frac 1 2$, almost surely the graph you obtain is *the* random graph.

Comment: So this is the Rado graph, right? It's an initially surprising fact that the Rado graph with probability $\frac12$ is almost surely isomorphic to the Rado graph with probability 0.85932895347895738927235887234

Comment: One thing about the random (or Rado) graph is that every vertex has infinite degree, which might not be desirable from the OP's perspective.

Comment: On the other hand, it is easy to see that if $G$ is a connected graph with the property that for *every* edge $e\in E$, $G$ is isomorphic to $G\setminus \{e\}$, then indeed every vertex must have infinite degree (otherwise you can repeatedly delete edges from around a vertex of finite degree to isolate it, contradicting the connectedness assumption).

Answer (score 5):

Take the graph with the integers as its vertex set and with edges {n, n+1} for all n>=0. Now remove the edge {0,1}

Comment: When you remove an edge, you leave its endvertices. So the graph you get will be disconnected.

Comment: it was disconnected to begin with...

Comment: I am sure the OP meant a connected graph but forgot to add this condition.

Comment: Then take ${\mathbb Z} \times \{0,1\}$, with "horizontal" edges $((n,i), (n+1,i))$ for all $n$ and $i$, and "vertical" edges $((n,0),(n,1))$ for $n \ge 0$. This is connected. And remove the first vertical edge $((0,0),(0,1))$.

Comment: To add on to @JukkaKohonen 's example, if you want a map where the isomorphism is transitive, take $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0, 1\}$, with all "horizontal" edges, as well as "vertical" edges $((n, 0), (n, 1))$ and $((n, 0), (n + 1, 1))$ for $n \geq 0$ (think of it as a "zig-zag" version).

Comment: To add to @hbjj's example, you could make it connected simply by adding one vertex that connects with everything, and make it a fixed point for the isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V=\{Fred\}\cup\mathbb N$.  Let $E=\{(Fred,p^3)\mid p \text{ is a prime }\}$.

Answer (score 1):

How about a graph $G=(V,E)$ consisting of infinitely many isolated vertices and infinitely many disjoint edges.  Like the random graph it has the property that *for all* $e\in E$, $G\simeq (V, E\setminus \{e\})$.